# Is possible to migrate a PhoneGAP app to PhoneGAP Build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Some one has try or made the process to migrate a cordova PhoneGAP app with plugins to PhoneGAP Build and compile on the cloud ?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of but I've done it the other way.

Just use the same code but you'll need to define all the plugins in the config. It should be pretty easy.